# C# EF Core LINQ directly to Model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

```
this.modelDataProductSubProductRate = this.contextSQL.ProductSubProductRate.Single(e => e.Id == this.parameter.Id.ToString());
```

I bind gridcontrol datasource to the context above and it works.

```
this.modelDataProductSubProductRate = this.contextSQL.ProductSubProductRate
.Join(this.contextSQL.LibraryCustomer,
pr => pr.Id, c => c.Id,
(pr, c) => new { pr })
.Single(e => e.pr.Id == this.parameter.Id.ToString());
```

But when I need more complex stuff like joining, I got error of anonymous type. Is there any way to make it work without the need to create another class inside the code? I already have the models with virtual columns if needed, why should I create another class?

```
var query = this.contextSQL.ProductSubProductRate
.Join(this.contextSQL.LibraryCustomer,
pr => pr.Id, c => c.Id,
(pr, c) => new { pr })
.Single(e => e.pr.Id == this.parameter.Id.ToString());
```

I noticed if I put the query on var, it works, but how to load into data context?

```
FormattableString cmd = $@"SELECT spr.*, c.Name CustomerName FROM ProductSubProductRate spr 
LEFT JOIN LibraryCustomer c ON (c.Id = spr.IdCustomer)
WHERE (spr.IdSubProduct = {IdSubProduct})";
this.contextSQL.ProductSubProductRate.FromSql(cmd).ToList();
```

If I use .FromSQL which I've been using for years with no problem, it works just like that. But I want to learn LINQ query whether method / syntax, both just don't work that way.

Comment: Can you provide the error message in detail for the mentioned *error of anonymous type*? Thanks.

Comment: CS0029 : Cannot implicitly convert type '<anonymous type: MJX.Model.modelDataProductSubProductRate pr>' to 'MJX.Model.modelDataProductSubProductRate'

Answer (score 1):

Please try like below and don't create anonymous object. Instead of anonymous object with `new { pr }` just return `pr`. Changes I made in code are to replace

`(pr, c) => new { pr }` with `(pr, c) => pr`

and

`.Single(e => e.pr.Id ==` with `.Single(e => e.Id ==`

```
var query = this.contextSQL.ProductSubProductRate
            .Join(this.contextSQL.LibraryCustomer,
                pr => pr.Id, c => c.Id,
                (pr, c) => pr) 
            .Single(e => e.Id == this.parameter.Id.ToString());
```

Comment: It works, I guess I will take time searching about anonymous and what is it for. Also based on the .FromSQL query, there is a column I need "c.Name CustomerName", from the joined customer table, how do you put it on the current LINQ? I assume putting => pr means only loading everything in pr table. Maybe that is what anonymous for?

Comment: @VincentKrisna Yes you can do projections with an anonymous object. Example: https://entityframeworkcore.com/querying-data-joining. The problem with your code above was that you didn't define any properties inside that anonymous object. That object also won't be assignment-compatible with your model class. But: you could also project _to_ a new instance of an appropriate model class.